# can't load sql dump to the containered mariadb

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am trying to make a dockerized mariadb database. In this database i need to load sql dump while build.

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:3.18.2

WORKDIR /Database

COPY . /Database

#install mysql and dependencies

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN apk add --no-cache mysql mysql-client openrc bash

# start mysql server

RUN mkdir /run/mysqld

RUN mysql_install_db --user=root

RUN mysqld -u root --data=./data &> /dev/null &

#RUN rc-service mariadb start

# load data to database

RUN mariadb -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE passwords;"

RUN mariadb -u root -p < dump.sql

EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

But when I build container, I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

As i understand it appears when mariadb is not running, but if i uncomment the `RUN rc-service mariadb start` i will get another error:

```
 * WARNING: mariadb is already starting
The command '/bin/sh -c rc-service mariadb start' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

i have tried to enter the container's shell and start mariadb manualy but it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker build stages are independent and you can't run background process in the `RUN` stages and have them still running on the next step.

`rc-service`, `systemctl`, `service` etc won't run because there is no `init` or openrc process running which these commands connect to.

The easiest way to generate a container is to base it on the initial image:

```
FROM mariadb:lts
COPY dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

This will initialize the database on startup.

If you want a truly pre-generated image:

```
FROM mariadb:lts
COPY dump.sql /

RUN echo '[mariadb]\ndatadir=/data' > /etc/mysql/conf.d/localdata.cnf ; mkdir /data ; mariadb-install-db ; mariadbd --bootstrap < dump.sql; chown -R mysql: /data ; rm /dump.sql
```

Note this won't have any database passwords setup. Also the `dump.sql` will begin with:

```
CREATE DATABASE passwords;
use passwords;
...
create table ....
```