# mariadb is unable outside of the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I want to run service with dockerized mariadb. when i run the container it does't shutdown so i think i can connect to mariadb via `mysql -h connected_ip -P connected_port -u root -p`. it responses by asking for password so i type it. but i get infinity loading after entering the password. it also disallow the next container to start.
here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb:11

COPY . /

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password123#@!

EXPOSE 3306
```

here is docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3"


services:

  client_connector:
    build: ClientConnector/

    command: python main.py

    ports:
      - 80:80

    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  mysql:
    build: Mysql/

    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password123!@#
      - USER=passwords
      - PASSWORD=P@ss\/\/0rd$
      - DATABASE=passwords
      - BACKUP_DIR=/Database

    command: ./entrypoint.sh

    ports:
      - 8080:3306

    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=Password123#@!
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 55
```

and entrypoint.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir $BACKUP_DIR

# start process and get it's pid

/etc/init.d/mariadb start & pid=$!

echo "mariadb pid is " $pid

# load database

mariadb -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD < dump.sql

# wait for stop

while kill -0 $pid >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    wait $pid
done

# Dump the MySQL database
mysqldump -u $USER -p$PASSWORD $DATABASE > $BACKUP_DIR/$DATABASE.sql
```

Comment: Make sure you're connecting to the right port... your sql instance shows 8080:3306, which means the sql server expects traffic at port 8080 and not 3306

Comment: FYI [mysqlping as healthcheck won't work and is wrong](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-server-docker-official-images-healthcheck-without-mysqladmin/). And `mysql*` named executables aren't in the container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't load sql dump to the containered mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550551/cant-load-sql-dump-to-the-containered-mariadb)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question? What is "unable outside the container"? What are you trying to achieve in a broader sense?

Comment: Your `command:` runs _instead of_ the normal container command.  Reading through your script carefully, it will exit as soon as the `/etc/init.d` script completes, which will be very quickly.  I'd remove both `command:` lines from the Compose file, and run this dump/restore script from somewhere else (maybe the host, connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8080).

Comment: The existence of a pid doesn't qualify the mariadb service as ready. Best look for the existence of its socket. Probably better to start mariadbd directly in the background too.